# Particle Js appear on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to set particle js as my background for my website. I am trying to apply this:

https://codepen.io/nikspatel/pen/aJGqpv

I tried to set its css as: `position: fixed; z-index: -10;` as I want it to fix in the position and I need the particle to be seen even if I scroll down.

It works fine once I enter the site but when I scroll down, it's not working as it should be. The particle does not follow the cursor anymore. Once I scroll down more, the particle just goes missing. I also tried to set it as an iframe background but stops working once I move my cursor through a div, the particle just sticks there.

This is what happened : [http://mycontinent.com.my/test](http://mycontinent.com.my/test/)

This is something I am trying to do : https://mahno.com.ua/en

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set the same value for the "detect_on" property in particles-js config

```
interactivity": {
   "detect_on": "window"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 body,
    html {
        height: 100%
    }

#particles-js canvas {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .8s ease, -webkit-transform 1.4s ease;
    transition: opacity .8s ease, transform 1.4s ease
}

#particles-js {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -10;
    top: 0;
    left: 0
}
```

Then I wrote  just after the body opening tag. Note that you can't see the canvas class because it's being generated by the particles.js library.

[Reference Site](https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/#nasa)

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping, I tried adding in the css, its not working either. Maybe you can check my [test site](http://mycontinent.com.my/test/). I think javascript is the problem for this. By the way, the reference site is different from what I am trying to do. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @Khai The issue is with the JS mention in above code-pen as i didnt take cursor position properly while scrolling, if set cursor at top and then scroll you see that at the bottom. Try to set what mention in official DOC of ParticleJS